# PametricPlot3D vs ContourPlot3D

Tags: plotting, graphics3d, parametric-functions

Basically, I don't know whether I am missing something mathematically fundamental or I misued *Mathematica*'s functions.

```
(*Roll,Pitch,Yawn*)
Rx = {{1, 0, 0}, {0, Cos[gamma], -Sin[gamma]}, {0, Sin[gamma], 
    Cos[gamma]}};
Ry = {{Cos[beta], 0, Sin[beta]}, {0, 1, 0}, {-Sin[beta], 0, 
    Cos[beta]}};
Rz = {{Cos[alpha], -Sin[alpha], 0}, {Sin[alpha], Cos[alpha], 0}, {0, 
    0, 1}};
R[alpha_, beta_, gamma_] = Rx.Ry.Rz;

OffsetTrans[d_, e_, f_] := {d, e, f};(*translation*)

X0[x0_, y0_, z0_] := {x0, y0, z0};
XPar[theta_, phi_, a_, b_, c_, alpha_, beta_, gamma_] = 
  R[alpha, beta, gamma].X0[x0, y0, z0] /. {x0 -> 
     a Cos[theta] Sin[phi], y0 -> b Sin[theta] Sin[phi], 
    z0 -> c Cos[phi]};
XParTrans[theta_, phi_, d_, e_, f_, a_, b_, c_, alpha_, beta_, 
  gamma_] = 
 OffsetTrans[d, e, f] + 
  XPar[theta, phi, a, b, c, alpha, beta, 
   gamma];(*parametric equations of arbitrary oriented and translated \
ellipsoid*)

ParametricPlot3D[
 XParTrans[theta, phi, 0, 0, 0, 7, 5, 3, Pi/3, Pi/3, Pi/3], {theta, 0,
   2 Pi}, {phi, 0, Pi}, 
 PlotStyle -> Directive[Orange, Specularity[White, 40], Opacity[0.5]],
  Mesh -> None]
```

[image]

```
(*Cartesian equation*)
X = {x, y, z};(*vector containing the three coordinate
axes*)
U = {Δx, Δy, Δz};(*a \
vector containing the distances that the center
of the ellipsoid is removed from the coordinate system origin {0,0,0}*)
\
V = {{1/a^2, 0, 0}, {0, 1/b^2, 0}, {0, 0, 1/
   c^2}};(*a shape matrix containing the semi-axes a,b,and c*)

RotatedEllipsoid[x_, y_, 
  z_, Δx_, Δy_, Δz_, a_, b_,
   c_, alpha_, beta_, 
  gamma_] = (X - U).R[alpha, beta, gamma].V.Transpose[
   R[alpha, beta, gamma]].(X - U);

ContourPlot3D[
 RotatedEllipsoid[x, y, z, 0, 0, 0, 7, 5, 3, Pi/3, Pi/3, Pi/3] == 
  1, {x, -7, 7}, {y, -5, 5}, {z, -3, 3}, 
 ContourStyle -> 
  Directive[Orange, Specularity[White, 40], Opacity[0.5]], 
 Mesh -> None]
```

[image]

Why the outputs are not the same?
Thanks.

Comment: @Jason B. Thanks for the editing. How, can insert greek characters when I make a post?

Comment: Try PlotRange->All

Comment: dimitris, you have @halirutan to thank for that.  https://github.com/halirutan/SE-Editor-Buttons

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to make sure that you have the same plotting range in the two different plots.  Since `ParametricPlot3D` automatically chooses the plotting range for you, you can just grab the plotrange from the parametric plot.

```
plot1 = ParametricPlot3D[
   XParTrans[theta, phi, 0, 0, 0, 7, 5, 3, Pi/3, Pi/3, Pi/3], {theta, 
    0, 2 Pi}, {phi, 0, Pi}, 
   PlotStyle -> 
    Directive[Orange, Specularity[White, 40], Opacity[0.5]], 
   Mesh -> None, BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}, ImageSize -> 400, 
   PlotPoints -> 50];

(* Get the plot range from the undocumented hidden function *)

prange = Charting`get3DPlotRange@plot1;

(* Extend the x,y, and z range just a little bit when feeding them as   the {x,xmin,xmax} values *)

drange = Flatten /@ Transpose[{{x, y, z}, 1.1 prange}];


plot2 = ContourPlot3D[
   RotatedEllipsoid[x, y, z, 0, 0, 0, 7, 5, 3, Pi/3, Pi/3, Pi/3] == 1,
    Evaluate@drange[[1]], Evaluate@drange[[2]], Evaluate@drange[[3]], 
   ContourStyle -> 
    Directive[Orange, Specularity[White, 40], Opacity[0.5]], 
   Mesh -> None, PlotRange -> prange, BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}, 
   PlotPoints -> 50, ImageSize -> 400];

Grid[{{plot1, plot2}}]
```

[image]